# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, java-8

```
04-Feb-2020 18:25:39.794 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6e2af876: defining beans [sessionFactory,sessionFactoryCCA,sessionFactorySSO,login,internalUsersMgmt,rolesMgmt,sessionManager,productManager,birtManager,templateManager,reportFileManager,dashboardDetailsDAO,configDynamicFilterDAO,oAMDataDAO,scheduledFileManager,cronTrigger,loginDAO,internalUsersDAO,applicationResourceDAO,reportTemplateStoreDAO,reportFileStoreDAO,scheduledFileStoreDAO,templateSchedulingParamDAO,reportUtilsDAO,rolesDAO,myFilter,userMasterDAO,userRoleDAO,sessionServiceDAO,permissionDAO,roleMenuDAO,rolePermissionDAO,ssoManagerDAO]; root of factory hierarchy
04-Feb-2020 18:25:39.794 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1403)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at net.sf.cglib.core.ClassEmitter.begin_class(ClassEmitter.java:77)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:173)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:215)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<clinit>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:321)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:855)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:774)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
        ... 25 more
04-Feb-2020 18:25:39.805 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
04-Feb-2020 18:25:39.889 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/omega] startup failed due to previous errors
04-Feb-2020 18:25:39.922 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [omega] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
04-Feb-2020 18:25:39.923 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [omega] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
04-Feb-2020 18:25:39.923 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [omega] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
04-Feb-2020 18:25:39.933 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [omega] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)` `
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)` `
```

Comment: I am using Tomcat8 , spring mvc 3.0.x, hibernate, in ANT tool. Please anyone suggest , very urgent for me. please help me

Comment: You are mixing jars from different versions of Spring or related frameworks. I strongly suggest to ditch ant and switch to maven or gradle (or at least introduce Ivy to manage your dependencies).

Comment: But I can’t remember any version of ASM where `ClassVisitor.visit` had that signature. It’s `visit(int version, int access,String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces)` whereas the stack trace says that this version of `net.sf.cglib.core.ClassEmitter` tries to invoke a method where the last parameter types are swapped, `visit(int, int, String, String, String[], String)`

Comment: Hi All, I have changed spring version 3.0.1 to 3.1.0 , still the same problem getting.

Comment: since we are working for existing older setup of ANT 9 , So we cann't go with MAven or gradle. Any guess , is there any hibernate jar is missing.. ?